# how to generate stacked progress bar in yii 1.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, yii

I trying to get this output using yii 1.1. It worked in bootstrap but how to implement stacked progress bar in yii.

```
    <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 35%">
    <span class="sr-only">35% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width: 20%">
    <span class="sr-only">20% Complete (warning)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 10%">
    <span class="sr-only">10% Complete (danger)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it worked and now doesn't, where has it gone wrong - can you explain?

Comment: The above code worked and show stacked bar in bootstrap but now i want the same result in yii framework. I have used the code below in multiple places for different conditions to make a stacked bar but gives only single separated bars.

Comment: `$this->widget(
     'bootstrap.widgets.TbProgress',
     array(
      'type'=>'success',
      'percent'=>$ap,
      )
     );`

Answer (score 0):

Use [YiiBooster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/getting-started.html) to achieve your goal.

Try this code for generate stacked progress bar.

```
$this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbProgress',
    array(
        'striped' => true,
        'stacked' => array(
            array(
                'context' => 'success',
                'percent' => 30,
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                    'title' => 'Hey! I am a title here.'
                )
            ),
            array('context' => 'warning', 'percent' => 35),
            array('context' => 'danger', 'percent' => 30),
        )
    )
);
```

For more info refer this [Docs](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/decorations/view/progress.html)